# TypeError: "send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address"

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, dapp-design

I have the following code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract CoinFlip {
   using SafeMath for uint;
   address public owner;
   uint public balance;
   uint public betLimit;
   uint public totalBets;
   uint public totalPayouts;

constructor(uint _betLimit) public {
    owner = msg.sender;
    balance = 0;
    betLimit = _betLimit;
    totalBets = 0;
    totalPayouts = 0;
}

function flipCoin(uint _bet) public payable {
    require(_bet > 0, "You must bet some Ether to play");
    require(_bet <= betLimit, "The bet must be less than or equal to the bet limit");

    totalBets = totalBets.add(_bet);
    balance = balance.add(_bet);

    uint randomNumber = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, msg.sender))) % 2;
    if (randomNumber == 0) {
        address(msg.sender).transfer(_bet.mul(2));
        balance = balance.sub(_bet.mul(2));
        totalPayouts = totalPayouts.add(_bet.mul(2));
    }
}

function disable() public {
    require(msg.sender == owner, "Only the owner can disable the contract");
    selfdestruct(owner);
}
}
```

With the following Error Code:

TypeError: "send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address".
--> contracts/4_CoinFlip.sol:31:13:
|
31 | address(msg.sender).transfer(_bet.mul(2));
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

What am i doing wrong?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a similar question asked previously about this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67341914/error-send-and-transfer-are-only-available-for-objects-of-type-address-payable

TLDR:

Starting in **Solidity 0.8.0**, `address(this)` is of type `address` instead of `address payable`

[image]

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/080-breaking-changes.html

You need to wrap the `address(msg.sender)` to be `payable(address(msg.sender))`

Additional:

You may want to avoid using `transfer` & `send` (use `.call` instead)
https://consensys.net/diligence/blog/2019/09/stop-using-soliditys-transfer-now/

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. This was not quite clear to me until somebody told me the right way. The compiler for that works so far. Im a beginner in solidity, so im just learning.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of things.

First of all, for your syntax error it's supposed to be `payable(msg.sender).transfer();`.

Now logic wise, note that your contract is easily exploitable, a simple smart contract that reverts the transaction if it loses the game can be created, like so :

```
contract attacker {
  function pwn() public payable {
    uint balanceBefore = address(this).balance;
    YourContract.flipCoin{value: msg.value}(msg.value); // Yes this is dumb but we're coming back to it later
    // flipCoin pays out instantly if we win, so we  can do
    if(address(this).balance < balanceBefore) {
      revert();
    }
  }
}
```

Or even better, by simulating your logic

```
function pwn() {
  uint randomNumber = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, address(this)))) % 2; // address(this) is msg.sender for the called contract
  // Only call the function if the outcome is positive
  if (randomNumber == 0) {
    YourContract.flipCoin{value: msg.value}(msg.value);
  }
}
```

Also, you're using a `balance` variable to keep track of the contracts balance and a `_bet` param in your flipCoin function that specifies of the amount of ETH betted when you don't need to, since these values are  already globally available in the EVM. The Ether value of a transfer is `msg.value`, and the balance of an address is `address().balance` ([docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html#special-variables-and-functions)). Doing it the way you  are is dangerous because it  allows people to lie on the amount they're betting  by setting `msg.value` and `_bet` to two different values when calling `flipCoin()`
A version of flipCoin() that uses those would be

```
function flipCoin() public payable {
    require(msg.value > 0, "You must bet some Ether to play");
    require(msg.value <= betLimit, "The bet must be less than or equal to the bet limit");

    totalBets = totalBets + _bet;
//    balance = balance + _bet; You don't need that. Use address(this).balance if you need to access the ether balance of your contract

    uint randomNumber = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, msg.sender))) % 2;
    if (randomNumber == 0) {
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(msg.value * 2);
        // balance = balance - (msg.value * 2);
        totalPayouts = totalPayouts + (_bet * 2);
    }
}
```

And finally, you're using safeMath, which isnt needed with solidity 0.8+ as the built in operators now check for over/underflows (i replaced it with the built in operators in the above code).